# Highlight selenium clicks using AOP

Tags: javascript, java, spring, selenium, aop

I am trying to plug in js element highlighting to selenium framework. I have this code:

```
@Aspect
public class HighlightAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(* *.click())")
private void allClickMethods(){}

@Before("allClickMethods()")
public void proxyClick(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){
    WebElement element = (WebElement)joinPoint.getTarget();
    highlight(element, "green");
}

private void highlight(WebElement element, String color) {
    Browser.getBrowser().executeScript("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = '"+color+"'",  element);
    }
}
```

I initialize spring context in 'main' class like:

```
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_config.xml");
```

And my `src/main/resources/spring_config.xml` looks like:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
...
    <bean
            id="highlightAspect"
            class="com.<my_name_space>.HighlightAspect">
    </bean>
...
```

---

I don't receive any exceptions from JVM, but when I add a logger to `proxyClick` I see this method didn't happen to be executed. 
Please, help me to make it work.

Comment: Have you made sure that the class containing the click()-method is a Spring bean that is running in you ApplicationContext?

Comment: Nope. Thanks it could be a clue

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,

1. ProceedingJoinPoint can't be used with `@Before`, it's only available with `@Advice`
2. Even in `@Advice`, as soon as you initiate the advice to proceed (i.e. click happens), there is NO guarantee that the element will be present in the DOM.